Convertir un valor ingresado en cm y mostrar la equivalencia a metros, yardas, pies, pulgadas en emu8086

Crear un algoritmo que convierta y muestre un valor ingresado en
centímetros a yardas, metros, pies y pulgadas.

org 100h  

.data
message1 db "Ingrese el valor en centimetros: $"
message2 db 13,10, "Equivalente en metros: $"
message3 db 13,10, "Equivalente en yardas: $"
message4 db 13,10, "Equivalente en pies: $"
message5 db 13,10, "Equivalente en pulgadas: $"
valor_cm dw 0
metros dw 0
yardas dw 0
pies dw 0
pulgadas dw 0

.code

start: 
    ; Inicializacion del segmento de datos
    mov ax, @data
    mov ds, ax
    
    ; Mostrar el mensaje para ingresar el valor en centímetros
    mov dx, offset message1
    mov ah, 09h
    int 21h

    ; Llamar a la subrutina para leer el numero ingresado por el usuario
    call ReadInteger
    mov valor_cm, ax ; Guardar el valor en la variable

    ; Conversion a metros
    mov ax, valor_cm
    mov bx, 100         
    xor dx, dx          ; Limpiar DX para la división
    div bx              ; AX = valor_cm / 100
    mov metros, ax      ; Guardar el resultado en metros

    ; Conversion a yardas (1 yarda ˜ 91.44 cm)
    mov ax, valor_cm
    mov bx, 9144
    xor dx, dx
    div bx
    mov yardas, ax

    ; Conversion a pies (1 pie ˜ 30.48 cm)
    mov ax, valor_cm
    mov bx, 3048
    xor dx, dx
    div bx
    mov pies, ax

    ; Conversion a pulgadas (1 pulgada ˜ 2.54 cm)
    mov ax, valor_cm
    mov bx, 254
    xor dx, dx
    div bx
    mov pulgadas, ax

    ; ---- Mostrar los resultados ----
    
    ; Mostrar metros
    mov dx, offset message2
    mov ah, 09h
    int 21h
    mov ax, metros
    call WriteInteger    
    
    ; Mostrar yardas
    mov dx, offset message3
    mov ah, 09h
    int 21h
    mov ax, yardas
    call WriteInteger
    
    ; Mostrar pies
    mov dx, offset message4
    mov ah, 09h
    int 21h
    mov ax, pies
    call WriteInteger
    
    ; Mostrar pulgadas
    mov dx, offset message5
    mov ah, 09h
    int 21h
    mov ax, pulgadas
    call WriteInteger
    
    ; Termina el programa
    mov ah, 4Ch
    int 21h  
    
; ---- Subrutina para leer un número entero ----
ReadInteger PROC
    xor ax, ax          
    xor bx, bx          
    xor cx, cx          

ReadLoop:
    mov ah, 01h         
    int 21h
    cmp al, 13          
    je DoneReading
    sub al, '0'         
    cmp al, 9           
    ja InvalidInput
    mov bl, al         
    mov dx, 10          
    mul dx              
    add ax, bx         

    inc cx              
    cmp cx, 3           
    je DoneReading      
    jmp ReadLoop       

InvalidInput:
    ; Manejo de entrada inválida (opcional)
    mov ax, 0           
    ret

DoneReading:
    ret
ReadInteger ENDP

; ---- Subrutina para mostrar un número entero ----
WriteInteger PROC
    push ax
    push bx
    push cx
    push dx

    mov bx, 10
    xor cx, cx
    mov dx, 0
    cmp ax, 0
    jne ConvertLoop
    mov dl, '0'
    mov ah, 02h
    int 21h
    jmp WriteIntegerEnd

ConvertLoop:
    xor dx, dx
    div bx
    push dx
    inc cx
    cmp ax, 0
    jne ConvertLoop

DisplayDigits:
    pop dx
    add dl, '0'
    mov ah, 02h
    int 21h
    loop DisplayDigits

WriteIntegerEnd:
    pop dx
    pop cx
    pop bx
    pop ax
    ret
WriteInteger ENDP

END start

El problema que presento es que si yo ingreso 100 cm, el resultado que me arroja en metros es 25 en yardas, pies me da 0 y pulgadas 10, pero obviamente no es correcto.

¿Tu subrutina ReadInteger tiene parámetros? Si, sí, entonces te falta pasárselos. No conozco bien MASM, pero creo que te falta acceder a la memoria, por que a mi parecer solo estás haciendo punteros a esas direcciones de memoria. No puedo proporcionar más detalles por que necesito analizar más tu código. Lo más probable es que no vuelva a responder por que se me olvidará, pero si me acuerdas,  con gusto te ayudo.
